# Count values by specific key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

### Problem

I have one tricky question how to count the value of key `amount` only if key `name_pay` equal to `Click`. I wrote PHP script which count only amount in array.
I somehow tried to change `array_key_exists` to `array_count_values()` but that was a mistake.

### Array

```
Array
(
[2016-05-31 00:00:00] => Array
    (
        [Основной долг] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [type_pay] => 0
                        [oper_type] => 4
                        [name_pay] => CLICK
                        [name_oper] => Основной долг
                        [time_pay] => 2016-05-31 00:00:00
                        [amount] => 1971022
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [type_pay] => 1
                        [oper_type] => 4
                        [name_pay] => Наличные
                        [name_oper] => Основной долг
                        [time_pay] => 2016-05-31 00:00:00
                        [amount] => 564550
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [type_pay] => 2
                        [oper_type] => 4
                        [name_pay] => Терминал
                        [name_oper] => Основной долг
                        [time_pay] => 2016-05-31 00:00:00
                        [amount] => 122714
                    )

            )

        [Депозит] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [type_pay] => 1
                        [oper_type] => 3
                        [name_pay] => Наличные
                        [name_oper] => Депозит
                        [time_pay] => 2016-05-31 00:00:00
                        [amount] => 1175942
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [type_pay] => 2
                        [oper_type] => 3
                        [name_pay] => Терминал
                        [name_oper] => Депозит
                        [time_pay] => 2016-05-31 00:00:00
                        [amount] => 1316410
                    )

            )

        [] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [type_pay] => 100
                        [oper_type] => 
                        [name_pay] => Терминал
                        [name_oper] => 
                        [time_pay] => 2016-05-31 00:00:00
                        [amount] => 843795
                    )

            )

        [Итого] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [click_count] => test
                        [bill_count] => test
                        [terminal_count] => test
                        [time_pay] => 2016-05-31
                        [count_all] => test
                        [name_oper] => Итого
                    )

            )

    )

 )
```

### PHP

```
$click = 0;
    foreach($data["reports"][1] as $v) {
        if(array_key_exists('amount', $v)) $click++;
    }
```

Comment: `if (array_key_exists('name_pay', $v) && $v['name_pay'] == 'CLICK') { #@todo }`

Comment: where count of amount value? I need count value of 'amount' if ['name_pay'] == 'CLICK'

Comment: ... `&& array_key_exists('amount', $v)) { $total += $v['amount'] }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
$click = 0;
foreach($data["reports"][1] as $v) {
    $click += (isset($v['name_pay']) && $v['name_pay'] == 'CLICK')? $v['amount']:0;
}
```

Am not really sure what `$data["reports"][1]` is in your code but since that is what you were iterating, I am using that same.